# VPN Client for OS X

Tags: osx, vpn

I would like to work occasionally from home and I need a [*Virtual Private Network (VPN)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) client for OS X (10.9).

A plus point would be if it's for free but I'm also willing to pay for the software.

It needs to support [Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol).

I'd like it to have good [encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) and my company network requires at least support form/strength of encryption.

Comment: What kind of features do you expect from this? Why is the built-in client not satisfactory?

Comment: Someone flagged this for reopening. Until it is edited to address what features you need this is not a well written question so I for one am not re-opening it. @Dirty-flow I'll propose an edit with some blanks to be filled it that will make it better and possiby reopenable.

Comment: You can use [Viscosity](https://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity/), an OpenVPN client for Mac & Windows which provides SSL/TLS Client support and you can easily configure your CA/Cert/Key/Tls-Auth certificates.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the VPN client built into macOS by Apple.

- Just open Network Preferences
- click the plus(+)
- Select VPN

See [Apple’s instructions for macOS Sierra](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25513?locale=en_US).